# Creating AngluarJS Apps but don't have a server side option for SEO Friendly URLs. Will This Work?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, routes, cloaking

I am creating an angular app that is hosted on a webserver that doesn't allow me to edit htaccess files or webconfig. There is no server side language option available which means no middleware for creating HTML snapshots. This is a high dollar CRM with webstore and no option of switching hosts.

So I have come up with my own "solution" to the issue. Would it be considered ok to create hyperlinks that link to url's that will generate the same view that will be updated by an onClick event. This way the user will see the content loaded immediately, but bots will have to reload the page at the new url to see the page content.

**Example:**

```
<a href="/view-2.html" onClick="updateState('#/view-2')">View 2</a>
```

I'm struggling to find a good solution to this issue, and I know others have to be in the same situation as me when it comes to development. The code above is just a visual reference to what I am referring to.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at 
[grunt-html-snapshot](https://github.com/cburgdorf/grunt-html-snapshot)

Comment: Thanks for the response. Grunt is not installed on our server and I don't have any way to login to the server to install npm and grunt. I wish I could though.

Answer (score 0):

After implementing this and testing this, it does work well. Google sees them as new pages and the user never has to worry about loading new content.